# When using the word “you” to mean a group of people (like in a blogpost) what sense of the word is it?

Tags: pronouns

I cannot remember the proper word to use, and it’s driving me batty. I can imagine the sentence in my head “I’m not saying you, as in you, Katherine, I mean “you” in the _____ sense of the word. I mean you as in society in general.”

Can anyone hazard a guess at what I’ve forgotten? Thank you so much.

Comment: Generic perhaps?

Comment: Side note, if you want to seem fancy and avoid confusing use "one" instead

Comment: Try _plural_; after all, _you_ swings both ways.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_you

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is "collective." Hope this helps. Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Agree with Omar. Collective is a good word for it.